# How is the distance explained as per theology?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Kursi is at a distance of 4000 years from earth.

> Ibn Mas’ood said: Between the first heaven and the one above it is (a distance of) five hundred years. Between each of the heavens is (a distance of) five hundred years. Between the seventh heaven and the Kursiy is (a distance of) five hundred years. Between the Kursiy and the water is (a distance of) five hundred years, and the Throne is above the water. Allaah is above the Throne, and nothing whatsoever of your deeds is hidden from Him. (narrated by Ibn Khuzaymah in al-Tawheed, p. 105; by al-Bayhaqi in al-Asmaa’ wa’l-Sifaat, p. 401).

This report was classed as saheeh by Ibn al-Qayyim in Ijtimaa’ al-Juyoosh al-Islamiyah, p. 100; by al-Dhahabi in al-‘Uluw, p. 64).

Comment: Are you sure it is "years" ? Aren't there other translations using distance units ?

Comment: Yasir qadhi says it's the time in which a bird flies continuously.

Answer (score 1):

The metric measures of distance was not common to Arabs these days. (and not even invented). 
The most common way to describe distance was in trade conovy trip time.
So this will lead to another question by which method time is measured is it a walking time or running or riding a horse... 
During the old days of Arab trade trips between El Sham (Syriaian area) at North and yeman at South. Using time in a measure of distance is derived from trade conovy time. Where it takes around 6 monthes each 
So a one year of distance will equal the distance between north to south of the Arabian Peninsula.
You can read surat quraish (106) where the trip to South and North are mentioned as the trip of winter and summer